# why jquery mobile page on windows phone so small?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, windows-phone, mobile-website

I open http://widiastore.com/sample/jquery-mobile/ from my windows phone. The screenshoot of page is http://s16.postimg.org/iqztjqx1x/wp_ss_20130902_0001.png.
Why the widget of the page is so small? If I open it from android and blackberry it's very nice user interface.

Comment: add this inside `<head>` and try again `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the HTML maybe you can add the viewport metadata:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Insert this in between `<head>` and `</head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```